# Linked list. Another value is changed in added node when changing poiner

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have linked list `userStack` of type `user`

```
struct user {
    int id;                     // ID
    char login[20];             // login
    char password[32];          // password md5
    user *next;
};
```

That's function for adding nodes to it:

```
void addUser(user **userStack) {
    if (*userStack == NULL)
    {
        user *p = new user;
        *p = enterUser();
        p->next = NULL;
       *userStack = p;
    }
    else
    {
        user *p = new user;
        *p = enterUser(); / returns struct user (keyboard input)
        p->next = *userStack;
        *userStack = p;
    }
    printf("User is added successfully!\n");
}

user enterUser() {
     user *u = new user;
     int tmpID = -1;
     char tmpLogin[20];
     char tmpPass[20];
     char tmpPass2[20];
     std::string hashPass;
     system("cls");
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Введите id пользователя: ");
     scanf("%d", &tmpID);
     while (isUserExists(tmpID) || tmpID < 0){
         fflush (stdin);
         if (isUserExists(tmpID))
             printf ("!!! Пользователь с таким id уже существует. \n");
         if (tmpID < 0)
             printf ("!!! ID пользователя не может быть отрицательным! \n");
         printf("Введите id пользователя: ");
         scanf ("%d", &tmpID);
     }
     u -> id = tmpID;
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Введите имя пользователя: ");
     gets(tmpLogin);
     fflush(stdin);
     while (isUserExistsLogin(tmpLogin)){
         printf ("!!! Пользователь с таким именем уже существует. \n");
         printf("Введите имя пользователя: ");
         gets(tmpLogin);
         fflush(stdin);
     }
     strcpy(u -> login, tmpLogin);
     printf("Введите пароль пользователя: ");
     scanf ("%s", &tmpPass);
     printf ("Введите пароль повторно: ");
     scanf ("%s", &tmpPass2);
     while (strcmp(tmpPass, tmpPass2) != 0){
         if (strcmp(tmpPass, tmpPass2) != 0)
             printf ("!!! Пароли не совпадают!\n");
         printf("Введите пароль пользователя: ");
         scanf ("%s", &tmpPass);
         fflush (stdin);
         printf ("Введите пароль повторно: ");
         scanf ("%s", &tmpPass2);
     }
     hashPass = md5(tmpPass);
     strcpy(u->password, hashPass.c_str());
     printf("\n");
     return *u;
 }
```

When I'm adding first node all is OK.

But when I'm adding 2nd and other I have trouble in line `p->next = *userStack;`.
This line correctly changes pointer but adds garbage to the end of `password`.

That's my trouble.
Thanks.

Comment: "`user *p = new user;`". Do you mean to tag this `c` or `c++`?

Comment: Please show the code of `enterUser()`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `user *p = new user;` followed immediately by `*p = enterUser();` strongly suggests you overwrite the first `*p` value.

Comment: added `enterUser()`

Comment: Your `enterUser()` has a memory leak.  You allocate memory, and never save the pointer value returned by `new` anywhere so that it can later be deallocated.  Are you really supposed to be returning a `user` and not a `user *`?

Comment: The `user enterUser()` shoud be changed to `void enterUser(user *u)`. The `user *u = new user;` has to be removed and `enterUser` should be called from `addUser` as `enterUser(p)`. The rest can be kept as it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful comments!

Comment: Michael's suggestions are done. That's fine but trouble is still there.
1st user's md5: `ff33f1b12213e021c2c4a888141953ba`
2nd user's md5: `74d502a7131cdac90eecdfb0531c4e87pЌ.`

And how 2nd user's md5 can be stored in char[32]?

Comment: I mean `p->password` changes at line `p->next = *userStack;` from `74d502a7131cdac90eecdfb0531c4e87` to `74d502a7131cdac90eecdfb0531c4e87pЌ.`

Comment: `fflush(stdin);`is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in password array. Increasing length solved it.

Thanks for code optimization advices.